# Importing React Starter Kit website to github

Tags: github, react-starter-kit

I wrote a website using the React Starter Kit, and now I want to import it into github.

I tried just importing it using github's instructions, but it imported a clone of the original repository with comments about previous commits. Very weird.

Anyways, how can I import my new website into github?

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: If you want to remove commit history, remove `.git` folder, then do `git init` to initialize a new repo, then run `git remote add origin <your-repo-url>` to add your repository URL, then `git push origin master -u` to push the contents of your local repo to your GitHub repository.

Comment: Thanks! I think that'll work. I'll try it tomorrow morning and post back.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do:

```
rm -rf .git
git init
git add src docs ... <- rest of stuff you want to commit
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/..
git push -u origin master
```

That seemed to do the trick

Comment: `git add .` - will add all the files in the local filder (except those listed in .gitignore) to "staging" area, to be included into a commit when you run `git commit -m "Initial commit"`